# Folder permissions for Wordpress on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have recently created a new Wordpress site, on azurewebsites.net. After the initial instal, I updated the PHP version to 5.4 and then resarted the site.

I was having trouble creating new folders, and in paticular, a plugin wasn't working as I would have expected.

The plugin was the WPTouch plugin. I installed the plug, but each time I tried to upload a new image to the

```
/wp-content/uploads/wptouch/custom-icons
```

(via the plugin, this was the final destination) I was getting the error message:

There seems to have been an error.
Please try your upload again.

Within Web Matrix 2, I do not have the ability to create a new folder (I thought that I would create the folders myself, and see if that resolved the problem).

So my question is - is there an issue with the folder permissions, and if so, how can I get round this to make the Wordpress plugin work.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you at least read the folder permissions? If so, what are they? You are really talking about a server issue. WordPress is subservient to the server when it comes to file/folder permissions.

Comment: Sadily not - becuase I am using Web Matrix, I can't see the folder permissions. I will try and view them through FTP.

Comment: Look at the owner and group as well, if you can.

Comment: I don't have physical access to the server, and using Filezilla and normal FTP doesn't give me the info.

I can't SFTP to the website either, so I'm stuck. I'm 99% certain that I can't change the folder permissions, and unless the plugin is update it'll never work.

Comment: It may not be the plugin's fault. Ask you host for help. I don't think you have any other choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I CHMOD files/directories on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040814/how-can-i-chmod-files-directories-on-windows-azure)

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar issues (upgrading WP plugins on Azure Website) and have found the only way to upgrade these is to restart the services, manually delete the remnants in the plugins folder, and re-install.

It's far from ideal but I'm persisting with it for now..

Some more in depth explanations here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/8c4d17e9-520c-4d89-bc7d-efe923dd1a55