# How can I CHMOD files/directories on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, ftp, chmod, filezilla

I am using FileZilla FTP to right click and change a directories File Permissions as I do on many other sites/servers. For some reason this is not working in Windows Azure. It outputs in FileZilla "500 'SITE CHMOD 777 (mydirectory)': command not understood"

Any ideas?

Comment: Windows filesystem permissions don't work like that.

Comment: You're misunderstanding relative paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hack solution to delete files on Azure:

1. Stop your website from the management console (https://manage.windowsazure.com)
2. Open up the FTP site in Filezilla
3. Rename the directory that has the problem to anything else (Possibly an optional step, I dont know)
4. Delete the renamed directory
5. Restart your website.

That seems to do it.

Comment: This works very well, I wouldn't even call it a HACK . . . a bit inconvenient though.

Comment: While this is a solution for deleting files, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why the heck would you want to delete the folder in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

The Windows Azure portal has a "Console" for websites where you can execute some shell commands. One of them appears to be chmod (fileutils) 4.1. I was able to modify the permissions on a folder using this:

```
chmod -R 744 myfolder
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows Azure Websites is a Windows Server based server. Thus, file permissions don't work like in Linux (as @SLaks already mentioned).

However, the account your scripts (PHP/ASP.NET/node.js) are executed under has **full** access to the folder `/site/wwwroot`, as does your FTP user. Meaning that from your PHP you can do all fully privileged file access operations - Read, Write, Delete, Create, Create directories.
What you cannot do, and cannot be changed, is to **execute** scripts (which 0777 would give you in Linux).